# Can a single UML project in Visual Studio generate multiple assemblies?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uml

I've written a lot more code than UML, and so it stands to reason that I'd expect Visual Studio's treatment of UML objects to act similarly to that of code objects. In fact, VS goes to great lengths to imply a one-to-one relationship here, as you can reverse-engineer code to UML and use UML to generate code. And yet, while you can reference objects within a single modeling project, it seems you cannot reference objects in other modeling projects as you can reference classes, interfaces, and the like in one code project from another.

So, is there a best-practice on how to handle this situation? I could potentially keep all my UML in a single modeling project, and by use of namespaces separate them logically, but if the project I am modeling contains base classes to be shared between multiple projects as well as the project-specific components, I would rather not distribute everything as a single, monolithic assembly. So:

- Can VS2010/2012/2013 UML tools output from a single model project to multiple assemblies?
- Is there a way to share entities between multiple modeling projects I hadn't yet discovered?
- Alternately, would the custom T4 templates to support this be easier to write than I suspect?
- Are there other tools that can achieve the above from a UML model created in VS?

It seems as if the best way to handle this would be a modeling project to contain the shared components, another for the project-specific componets as well as "fake" entities with the same name as the shared one I'd reference if I could. Then, after generating code with the tool, manually replace references to the "fake" entity in the generated code to the real one.